# Download data from blob url

Tags: javascript, apache

I am creating an application that records audio from mic and gives an option to download it to the local drive. here is a piece of my   code that generates an audio link with a timestamp.

```
stopRecording(function(AudioBLOB){

                var url = URL.createObjectURL(AudioBLOB);
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                var au = document.createElement('audio');
                var hf = document.createElement('a');

                au.controls = true;
                au.src = url;
                hf.href = url;
                // Important:
                // Change the format of the file according to the mimetype

                hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
                hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
                li.appendChild(au);
                li.appendChild(hf);
                recordingslist.appendChild(li);
}, _AudioFormat);
            }, false);
```

How can I modify this code so instead of creating the link it would directly upload the file to my root folder.

Comment: Why don't you just send the blob upstream as base64?

Comment: @Rafael I am not expert in javascript. I am trying to modify a code that I found online

Answer (score 0):

This sends the `wav` upstream, POST /upload, encoded as base64, along with metadata. The server will have to decode `data` and save it to the file-system:

```
class Audio {
    static createPayload(audioBlob) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            const r = new FileReader();
            r.readAsDataURL(audioBlob);
            r.onloadend = function () {
                resolve(JSON.stringify({
                    filename: `${new Date().toISOString()}.wav`,
                    mimeType: 'audio/wav',
                    transferEncoding: 'base64',
                    data: r.result
                }));
            };
        });
    }
}

stopRecording(async function (audioBlob) {
    const payload = await Audio.createPayload(audioBlob);

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(payload);
}, false);
```

Comment: is this `/upload` a directory on server ?

Comment: Is it not possible to directly upload it to the folder?

Comment: If the client had direct access to the server's file-system, that would be scary. The server always mediates the client/backend.